# Which java database should I use

Tags: java, database

I am new to databases. Now, I want to make 4 computers share the same database through LAN. So, which database would you recommend me to learn and how do you set up the location of the database be the specified by me?

Comment: i would suggest google , give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for free then go for mysql.You have not mentioned which operating system you use.Well mysql supportsmost of the operating systems.See this link for more info on [databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

Comment: Not [MariaDB](http://www.mariadb.org/) or [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) or [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am personally working in mysql and its has been liked by most of the users.Well there not only mysql or mariaDB or postgres.Well I answer only that which I use and feel good.